# Logic for users not to pick same user again?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, logic

I understand this is not the place probably to ask for help however, I don't have anything else to ask for it. So here I go with big hopes for an answer as I'm really stuck at logical part:

So here I have my own code, I'm trying to create a present draw app, however I'm failing to implement part on how to make so that same user in gift givers would not get drawn again by different people. In here I achieved so that User who inputs his name would not get drawn himself and I've spent quite some time already experimenting, but I hit rock bottom, and have no ideas, however I had a feeling that maybe another list would assist me however can't resolve on how at the moment.

```
import random

gift_givers = ["Danielius", "Vilte", "Loreta", "Irena", "Agne", "Linas", "Aiste"]

counter = 0
length = len(gift_givers)

while length >= counter:
    user_name = input("Hello, please tell me your name: ")
    if user_name in gift_givers:
        gift_givers.remove(user_name)
        random_receiver = random.choice(gift_givers)
        gift_givers.append(user_name)
    
        counter = counter + 1
        print(f"{user_name} will be secret santa of -> " + random_receiver)
        print(f"Counter is {counter}")
```

Comment: Can you clarify please what is your expected query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a text file or database and write to that file/db about who has been drawn. Use that to give your program state. for example, if user drawn -> write to text file -> on next draw exclude those in text file